# Vector Subspace question

Tags: linear-algebra

$X,Y,Z$ are subspaces of vector space $V$ s.t. $X + Z = Y + Z$, then is $X= Y.$ How to prove it?

If $X \oplus Z= Y\oplus Z$ then is $X = Y.$

Comment: No. Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$. If $X=\{\alpha(1,0) \colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $Y=\{\alpha(1,1)\colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $Z=\{\alpha(0,1)\colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$ then $X+Z=Y+Z=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Hashtag It may be more clear to write $X \cong Y$ rather than $X = Y$.

Comment: $X\oplus{Z}=Y\oplus{Z}$ does not mean that $X=Y$.  FOr example, let $X=\{(x,0)|x\in\mathbb{R}\},Y=\{(y,y)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}, Z=\{(0,z)|z\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  Then $X\oplus{Z}=Y\oplus{Z}$ since they both generate $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @njguliyev: please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $X=\{\alpha(1,0)\colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $Y=\{\alpha(1,1)\colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $Z=\{\alpha(0,1)\colon \alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then $X \oplus Z=Y \oplus Z=\mathbb{R}^2$, but $X \ne Y$.

Answer (score -2):

This is not true. $\mathbb{R}^2 \oplus \mathbb{R}^3 \cong \mathbb{R}^3 \oplus \mathbb{R}^2$ but $\mathbb{R}^2 \neq \mathbb{R}^3$. And there's not just the trivial example of order. In infinite dimensions, it can even be the case that $A \oplus B \cong C \oplus D$ and $A \cong C$ but $B \not \cong D$.

Comment: Your first example is not a counterexample to the question. For the second, you don't need infinite dimensions, see @njguliyev's comment.

Comment: @Rasmus I don't understand. Why is it not a counter-example? And njguliyev 's example is not such that $A \oplus B \cong C \oplus D$ and $A \cong C$ but $B \not \cong D$.

Comment: 1) Because the question asks for $C=D$ (in your notation). 2) Yes, it is.

Comment: I can't understand why the use of $\,A,B,C...\;$ to denote what the OP *already* established as $\,X,Y,Z...$ ...just to make things more confuse? Anyway, I think njguliyev's example indeed doesn't provide counter example to what Eric means (if i'm not totally confused already), but he in fact provides a counter example to the OP's first claim.

Comment: But my question was if A direct sum C = B direct sum C is A equivalent to C?. But i guess the previous comments do answer my question

Comment: @Hashtag Let $C$ and $B$ be any countable-dimensional spaces, and $A$ a finite dimensional space. Then $A \oplus C \cong B \oplus C$, but $A \not \cong B$.

Comment: @Rasmus In njgliyev's example, all three spaces are isomorphic. (They are not equal as subsets, but there is an isomorphism between them.) I assume (perhaps incorrectly) that $\cong$ is the correct interpretation of $=$, not subset equality.